# Exporting query results to an output file in cloud storage using Google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm working on a project involved with querying a bigquery server.

Until recently, the size of output was enough to fit in memeory as a pandas dataframe:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client(...)
query = client.query("SELECT * FROM my_table")
results = query.to_dataframe()
```

Now I got to a point where the result may be too large to fit in memory.

Ideally, I'd tel bigquery to export the results of a query as csv/parquet file into cloud storage.

Problem is, I'm not sure how can I do that using the python client library.

Is the mentioned above possible?

Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#python)

```
# from google.cloud import bigquery
# client = bigquery.Client()
# bucket_name = 'my-bucket'
project = "bigquery-public-data"
dataset_id = "samples"
table_id = "shakespeare"

destination_uri = "gs://{}/{}".format(bucket_name, "shakespeare.csv")
dataset_ref = bigquery.DatasetReference(project, dataset_id)
table_ref = dataset_ref.table(table_id)

extract_job = client.extract_table(
    table_ref,
    destination_uri,
    # Location must match that of the source table.
    location="US",
)  # API request
extract_job.result()  # Waits for job to complete.

print(
    "Exported {}:{}.{} to {}".format(project, dataset_id, table_id, destination_uri)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I saw this example but I'm not sure it's what I need.
In the example though I used a simple query which basically does nothing, but the real use case involves with more complex query.
Can u please explain if your suggested solution would work on such case? I mean what the `table_id`  would be?

Comment: I see. Try using `CREATER TABLE datasetname.tablename AS SELECT *` or [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#writing_query_results) example. This will create a table which can be exported to cloud storage.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideally, I'd tel bigquery to export the results of a query as csv/parquet file into cloud storage.

You can use below BigQuery statement

```
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://bucket/folder/*.csv',
  format='CSV',
  overwrite=true,
  header=true,
  field_delimiter=';') AS
SELECT * FROM my_table
```

Read more about [EXPORT DATA statement](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement)